# Error while adding with spread operator in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

while adding selected eid from the checkbox to the array  I am getting an error. this is my checkbox selection which is in Acomponent.

```
 const checkBoxSelection = (eID, e) => {
        console.log('eID', eID);
        console.log('e.target.value', e.target.checked);
        if (e.target.checked) {
            setCheckedItems([...checkedItems, eID]);
        } else {
            setCheckedItems((prevState) => [...prevState.filter((item) => item !== eID)]);
        }
    };
```

the checkbox is in Bcomponent. I am sending through pops.

```
<input type='checkbox' onChange={(e) => checkBoxSelection(data.id, e)} />
```

error is

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method
```

Comment: What is `checkedItems`?

Comment: `checkedItems` is not an array. Check it's contents by logging it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your initial values of `checkedItems` is not an Array . Please make sure you are passing the initial value as `[]`

```
const [ checkedItems, setCheckItems ] = useState([])
```

Also its not needed to spread an array returned from the `filter` as it returns a new Array .

```
setCheckedItems((prevState) =>prevState.filter((item) => item !== eID))
```